# How to prevent scroll for side navbar?

Tags: html, css

The side navbar has its own scroll but instead, I would rather have one side scroll in the main body. When you scroll the main, it should also display the additional side navbar information as well.

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/wzcya8b9/3/

**HTML**

```
<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#services">Services</a>
  <a href="#clients">Clients</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#services">Services</a>
  <a href="#clients">Clients</a>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <h2>Sidebar</h2>
  <p>This sidebar is of full height (100%) and always shown.</p>
  <p>Scroll down the page to see the result.</p>

</div>

</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 160px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
}


.main {
  margin-left: 160px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
  font-size: 28px; /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  margin:0
}

.container{
  display:flex
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 160px;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  /*overflow-x: hidden;*/
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.main {
  margin-left: 160px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
  font-size: 28px; /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#services">Services</a>
  <a href="#clients">Clients</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#services">Services</a>
  <a href="#clients">Clients</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#services">Services</a>
  <a href="#clients">Clients</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#services">Services</a>
  <a href="#clients">Clients</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#services">Services</a>
  <a href="#clients">Clients</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#services">Services</a>
  <a href="#clients">Clients</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#services">Services</a>
  <a href="#clients">Clients</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <h2>Sidebar</h2>
  <p>This sidebar is of full height (100%) and always shown.</p>
  <p>Scroll down the page to see the result.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I’d suggest using css grid or Flexbox.

You can read an in depth, example-giving article on it here.

https://alligator.io/css/css-grid-holy-grail-layout/

BASIC EXAMPLE

This could give you a 200px column and an expanding column which would fill the rest of the width of the page. The navbar would sit on the left and use the same scroll bar.

HTML

```
<div class=“wrapper”>
    <div class=“sidebar”></div>
    <div class=“main”></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 200px auto;
}
```

If you’d like the top of the navbar to stick to the top of the window, you could replace position:fixed with position:sticky.